# Action listener inside a fragment button not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am having a bottom tabbed activity with Home, Dashboard and Notifications tabs. Now by default android studio offers these tabs in the form of fragments. I have a button that is inside a fragment_home.xml but my current view is set to activity_main.xml.The button.onClick Listener inside fragment class does not seem to work. How can this be resolved?

Main Class...

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications).build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cutom_toolbar, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.menu2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Menu 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:rowOrderPreserved="false"
    grid:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image1"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        grid2:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        grid2:columnCount="2"
        grid2:rowOrderPreserved="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="TextView"
            grid2:layout_column="0"
            grid2:layout_row="0">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Lighting"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                grid2:layout_column="0"
                grid2:layout_gravity="fill"
                grid2:layout_row="0">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/light2"
                    grid2:layout_gravity="left" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="All Off"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment Class...

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

public Button button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    button = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you can post some relevant code to illustrate your problem, we can better help you.

Comment: Sorry for late comment. I have now updated the code.

Comment: This is backwards. Have the interface defined in the fragment, but have the activity implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear. if i am getting right then,
declare a global veriable inside your fragment.

```
public Button button;
```

initialize it to onViewCreated()

in your main activity

```
if(fragment.button != null){
   //fire action
}
```

Comment: @+id/imageView2, this view is in  fragment_home.xml layout thats inflated in HomeFragment. if you need to access the button inside your activity what you can do is set a callback. you can use an interface that you main activity implemented and when the button get pressed inside your fragment send data through the interface.

Comment: For this, I might have to communicate between fragment and main class? But I think that the same can be achieved only by Actionlistener in fragment class itself.

Answer (score 0):

The view elements that are declared in `fragment_home.xml` will need to be interacted with in the Fragment code and not the activity.

Using the NavHost means most of your code will be in the individual fragments and not in the activity hosting the fragments.

You could use an interface to communicate between the two if necessary.
You could also use a shared ViewModel to communicate - have the onClick listener in the fragment set an Observable in the ViewModel that the MainActivity is subscribed to.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I should define an interface X with the button.onClick code in that interface and then I shall implement it from my main class?

Comment: I think the best approach is to handle the onClick inside the home fragment code itself.  If you have to communicate between the activity and fragment there are a multitude of ways. A popular new method is to use a shared viewmodel.

Comment: Yup I just wanted an action listener on a button in my fragment. I have updated the code with the Fragment class having an action listener. But the action is not working, also Android studio is saying that class fragment1 is never used?